constexpr function not compiling post gcc 10
I have the following code snippet :
#include <iostream>

// Another function that takes a const char array reference
template <size_t N> 
constexpr 
int anotherFunction(const char (&str)[N]) {
    int ct = 0;
    for(int i=0; i< N; i++)
    {
        ct++;
    }
    return ct;
}

// emulate the functionality of another wrapper
#define WRAP(sev, str, ...) do { constexpr int ans = anotherFunction(str); std::cout << ans << std::endl;} while(0);


// Function template that takes a string literal and passes it to another function
template <size_t N, typename... Args>
void printString(const int& log, const char (&str)[N], Args&&... args) {
    WRAP(0, str, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


int main() {
    
    printString(0, "Hello, World! %s %d", 1, "hello");
    return 0;
}

This compiles fine until gcc 9, but since gcc 10 gives the following error:
<source>:25:53:   required from here
<source>:15:48: error: 'str' is not a constant expression
   15 | #define WRAP(sev, str, ...) do { constexpr int ans = anotherFunction(str); std::cout << ans << std::endl;} while(0);
      |                                                ^~~
<source>:19:5: note: in expansion of macro 'WRAP'
   19 |     WRAP(0, str, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      |     ^~~~
Compiler returned: 1

The corresponding godbolt link is :
https://godbolt.org/z/zn1a45qMY
I am trying to understand what changes were introduced by reading the changelog, but couldnot make sense of it yet. The above essentially mimics a thirdparty macro that I have been trying to encapsulate into a method in my project. What is going wrong here?
EDIT :
I understand that ans need not be a constexpr here. However the macro is actually trimmed down from the thirdparty interface where it is later set as the size of std::array. Hence it needs to be a constexpr(afaiu?).
Hence it is not desirable for me to change WRAP macro, however I am at freedom to make changes to printString() to allow the string literal to be passed to the macro. Can I do that somehow?
EDIT 2 :
Also it would be interesting to note that this example compiles and runs successfully in gcc14!

Just replace constexpr int ans with int ans? Function params are never considered to be constexpr inside of the said function. (But its return value can't be constexpr if everything it does is possible to do at compile-time.)

FWIW it is also rejected by clang and MSVC, see demo.

Oh, I just noticed that your function anotherFunction doesn't actually access str. Is that intentional? If so, I have to correct my answer.

If you only depend on N, not actually str, you can pass std::extent_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(str)>> directly to anotherFunction instead.

WRAP and anotherFunction are part of third party libraries, so I would not be able to change them readily. Is there something I can do with printString wrapper itself? (Updated the question with edit)

If WRAP can't be changed, you can alternatively create a dummy array constexpr char dummy[N]{}; in printString and pass that to the macro.

But, I guess the actual macro does something else, so that this doesn't work, because currently the macro doesn't make any practical sense.

Yes, the actual macro will be using the str to do a computation. With a string literal entering the macro, things work fine. Issue is when I try to wrap it within a function.

gcc 10 compiler no longer allows non-literal types to be used in constexpr expressions?

Before P2280, naming a reference that doesn't have its lifetime started during the constant expression evaluation and is not usable in constant expressions, even if there is never any access through the reference, always causes the expression to not be a core constant expression.
The parameter of a function can never be usable in constant expressions.
Therefore naming str in the initialization of ans, which you require to be a constant expression with constexpr, makes the initialization not a constant expression and ill-formed.
The old GCC 9 behavior before P2280 was a bug in that it was not standard-conforming.
P2280 was however accepted as a defect report, meaning that it also applies to previous C++ editions. A newer compiler version that implements the defect report should therefore accept the program again. GCC implements P2280 starting with version 14.
However, this all applies only if anotherFunction doesn't actually use str other than passing it on by-reference.

However, assuming you actually access str in anotherFunction:
The value of a function parameter is never usable in a constant expression. You are trying to force the initialization of ans to be a constant expression depending on str, but str is a function parameter that doesn't have a fixed compile-time known value. Its value depends on the call site of the function. So ans would also change at each call site making its value not a fixed constant expression as constexpr would require.

But your code doesn't need constexpr there anyway. Just remove it. You are not trying to use ans in a constant expression at compile-time.

This indeed is very helpful. P2280 was also an interesting read! In my case I am assured behaviorwise that printString will always be called with a string literal. Is there some way to model this?

@ArchismanPathak See my comments on your question. But if the macro does something else, e.g. actually uses ans where a compile-time known value is required and needs to use the value of str as well, then in C++17 the only way is to store the literal in a constexpr static array before calling printString and then passing the array as a by-reference template argument to printString (instead of function argument). It doesn't work as function parameter. With C++20 you can use a std::array-like type as class-type NTTP for printString instead, allowing you to drop the array variable.
